# Get filesize on 'change function' before upload using Extjs

Tags: extjs, file-upload, extjs4.1

I want to get filesize when change function run. I try more but anything didn't work.
How can i do that thanks

```
   {
        xtype: 'filefield',
        name: 'upfile[]',
        buttonConfig: {
            text: 'add'
        },
        listeners: {
              'change': function(f, value){
                    alert(f.size); // not filesize
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to support most browser-versions this is not possible because JavaScript don't has access to that information. The best workarround is to autostart a upload and abort it as soon as you have the header. Now you have the filesize. Just send it back in the answer of the request

Comment: Hi @trungkien you can refer the link http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?158445-How-can-i-get-the-size-of-the-file-before-upload

Comment: I tried use javascript (in http://i.ndigo.com.br/2012/01/javascipt-checking-the-file-size/ or https://www.classle.net/faq/check-file-size-using-javascript-uploading) to get size but not working on some browser or old version browser (ex: ie 9 is not working ...). maybe Jquery do better in http://forum.jquery.com/topic/checking-file-size-before-uploading-it but Jquery i just check little browser and don't know embed it to extjs :(

Comment: @sra can u give me a example using server(php,..) to check before upload. i using $.ajax({
                                type: "HEAD",
                                url: f.getValue(),
                                success: function(msg){
                                    alert(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Length') + ' bytes');
                                }
                        }); but not working

Answer (score 1):

1. the only universal solution is to upload the file to the server and get the file size back
2. for modern browsers (IE10 and all the others), you can use the HTML5 FileReader API

   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader
3. for IE 9 or less you can use Hariharan's solution

Answer (score 1):

```
listeners:{
    change:function(inputFile, value){
            console.log(inputFile.fileInputEl.dom.files[0].size)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is possible with `ActiveX Objects`.

```
function getSize()
{
    var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
    var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
    var size = thefile.size;
    alert(size + " bytes");
}
```

Please refer below link

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?158445-How-can-i-get-the-size-of-the-file-before-upload

Comment: It's not working in some browser. i just test in Chrome Version 27.0.1453.116 m - not working, Firefox 21.0 - not working :(

Comment: @trungkien Well, that's because ActiveX objects are a Microsoft thing and therefore only exist within the InternetExplorer ;)